# state and test the null hypothesis of rank on median starting salary?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I am learning how to use R Studio for a class and the question asks to state and test the effect of the rank of a law school from a data set on the median starting salary with a regression. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!!!
The regression model is:
log(salary)=β0+β1LSAT+β2GPA+β3log(libvol)+β4log(cost)+β5rank+u